# Rx 2.1: How to subscribe and observe on Dispatcher correctly

Tags: windows-phone-8, system.reactive, observable

First of all, I'm using the most recent of Rx, that is 2.1. As far as I understand, lots of things have changed when Rx turned 2, so I'm really looking forward to receive an up-to-date answer. Thanks in advance.

I'm implementing a classic task for Rx: observing text of TextBox (AutoCompleteBox from WPToolkit to be exact), in order to provide a list of suggestions to user. Suggestions are fetched from the network, and I want to use these ordinary Rx goodies, like Throttle, DistinctUntilChanged, etc.

I'm also using recently released portable HttpClient for Windows Phone 8, since it provides task-based asynchronous API, which is nice.

The problem I'm having is the cross-thread access while *reading* the `Text` value of 'AutoCompleteBox`. Here is the code:

```cs
var http = new HttpClient();
var searchFunc = Observable.FromAsync<HttpResponseMessage>(() => 
            http.GetAsync(FormatUrl(SEARCH_URL, "DE", new GeoCoordinate(51, 13), searchBox.Text /* <-- causes exception */, 10, "")));

var uithread = new SynchronizationContextScheduler(SynchronizationContext.Current);
var textChange = Observable.FromEventPattern<RoutedEventArgs>(searchBox, "TextChanged")                             
        .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(800))
        .DistinctUntilChanged()     
        .SubscribeOn(uithread)           
        .SelectMany(searchFunc)                
        .Select(async (resp) => SearchResultsParser.ParseSearchResults(await resp.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync(), new GeoCoordinate(51, 13)))
        .Select(async (results) => searchBox.ItemsSource = await results)
        .ObserveOn(uithread)
        .Subscribe();
```

Exception happens when `searchFunc` is executed. I see from VS that it executes on a Worker Thread, despite I use SubscribeOn.

Here's the example using `SynchronizationContextScheduler`, but I've also tried just `SubscribeOnDispatcher`, with the same result. Looks like I'm missing something important with this `ObserveOn` stuff, or maybe regarding `Observable.FromAsync`. Could you kindly point me to my mistake?

Comment: That code you pasted, where is it executing from? Inside a form/control? (basically, "is it for sure executing on the ui thread?")

Comment: Yes, it's indeed executed on the UI thread. This is the page's constructor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`SubscribeOn` is *almost* never what you want - you might think it means "Where my `Subscribe` method runs", but it actually means "Where the actual wiring to the `IDisposable` (and disposal) runs" - `ObserveOn` is the equivalent for "This is where I want my actual `Subscribe` code to execute"

Ref: [Observable.SubscribeOn and Observable.ObserveOn](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rxteam/archive/2009/11/21/observable-context-observable-subscribeon-and-observable-observeon.aspx)

Comment: Unfortunate naming, that.